# How to override buffer size on InputStream

Tags: asp.net

I am using .NET to post a form on a web page with HTTP method "POST". On the server, I read the data with:

```
Dim myStream As New System.IO.BinaryReader(Request.InputStream)
bytesRead = myStream.Read( myObject, lastIndex, bytesToRead)
```

When reading data, the buffer size seems arbitrary, and doesn't care about the value of bytesToRead, as long as it's less than the remaining stream data size.

Is there any way of setting the buffer size of Request.InputStream on the page level? I'm suspecting this can only be done at the TCP level?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Because I want the client (web browser) to track progress of the post. With large buffersize, it's looks laggy for the user. I want a small buffersize, like 4096 bytes or so.

Comment: Interesting.  The post below describes how to do with with WebAPI, but that's the closest thing I could find:  http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: There's a BufferStream in .NET, but you can't use it on binary data, and I don't think it would help anyway. This must be a common problem, even Facebook fakes the progress bar when uploading images. Is it me, or is it strange that buffersize is not supported by the HTTP protocol?